# Chromecast screen goes black but still has audio

Tags: google-chrome, audio, video, chromecast

When casting a Chrome-tab from my Windows 10 machine to a Chromecast, after a while the screen goes black but continues to play audio. Without restarting I cannot stream any video from the browser. Even rebooting the Chromecast doesn't resolve the issue.

What can I do to solve this black screen appearing?

Comment: I'm still having this issue. It seems to be something to do with the PC as when i restart it the problem goes away for a short time.

Comment: By 'restarting' do you mean restarting Chrome or restarting your computer? Approximately how long is it until the black screen appears? A few seconds, a few minutes or after extended viewing?

Comment: Yes, I mean restarting the pcs. Sometimes it's 20 minutes, sometimes it's hours. It's never instant though. I'll make my question clearer later.

Comment: These are well-known problems with Chromecast. Many solutions exist that work for some. Among them is (1) Switching to TV/Cable and back to HDMI, (2) Unplugging and replugging the Chromecast repetitively for some seconds, (3) Reducing the casting quality to reduce network congestion, (4) Change Wifi channel.

Answer (score 2):

These are well-known problems with Chromecast. Many solutions exist that work for some. Among them is :

1. Switching to TV/Cable and back to HDMI
2. Unplugging and replugging the Chromecast repetitively for some seconds
3. Reducing the casting quality, to reduce network congestion
4. Change WiFi channel, to avoid intermittent interference

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had tried all these solutions already, but they don't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Several things to try on the Chromecast side:**

1. Make sure it has a strong wifi signal and a non-conflicting IP address.
2. Make sure it's not over-heating, does it feel particularly warm to the touch?
3. Is it getting enough electricity?  The AC adaptor included with the Chromecast supplies 850ma do you have at least that much?

**Some things to try on the Computer:**

1. Does stopping and restarting the cast help?  Click the cast icon and click "Stop casting".  (See Image below)
2. Try removing the Chromecast Chrome extension, rebooting the computer and re-installing it.
3. Do you have another Chromecast or computer to test?  That might help us determine if the computer or Chromecast is at fault.  Try another computer or another Chromecast and update your question with the results.

**Some things to try on the TV:**

1. Does it work better in a different HDMI port?
2. Does your TV have any power saving features that could be turning or dimming the screen?

If you discover what is going on please update your question or mention which of the above suggestions was useful to you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try respond to all of you answers. The wi-fi signal is very good, but i don't think it is that as when i cast from compatible players like the BBCi player it never drops. The temp feel pretty low constantly. The Chromecast is plugged in using the mains. Restarting the cast doesn't make any difference. Rebooting the computer gets rid of the problem for a short while. I don't have another machine to test on. I only have 1 HDMI port. My TV does not have any power saving functions that i know of, but it only ever affects when i'm casting a tab.